# How to have Tkinter Label text change when after certain amount of time?

Tags: python, tkinter, time, var

I'm setting up a GUI Application, and I am having an issue with text changing on a Tkinter Label on a time.sleep() timer.

I have tried something like

```
label_text = Label(main_window, text="hello world")
time.sleep(3)
label_text = Label(main_window, text="hello world")
```

(take note that I have the grid system and tkinter window setup, I am just not going to show all code inside of this)

```
# Currently this is not working how I would like it to, but here is the code
main_window = tkinter.Tk()
label_text = Label(main_window, text="hello world")
time.sleep(3)
label_text = Label(main_window, text="hello")
label_text.grid(column=1, row=1)

main_window.mainloop()
```

and this

```
main_window = tkinter.Tk()
main_window.resizable(False, False)
main_window.geometry("500x900")

text = StringVar()
text.set("hello")
label = Label(main_window, text=text)
label.grid(column=1, row=1)
time.sleep(3)
text.set("anoefn")
main_window.update()

main_window.mainloop()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `label_text.text = "hello"`? That is, just changing the property of the existing variable?

Comment: I just did, sadly that didn't work. Thank you though.

Comment: What will this label be used for? Could the timer be replaced by a button? If not I think the best course of action is threading, but that is not ideal with Tkinter

Answer (score 3):

I think this does what you want.  You need to use tk_obj.after to get the timedelay.
In the code in the question sleep delays the calling of mainloop by 3 seconds.

```
main_window = tk.Tk()
label_text = tk.Label(main_window, text="hello world")

def on_after():
    label_text.configure( text="hello")

label_text.grid(column=1, row=1)
label_text.after(3000, on_after) # after 3000 ms call on_after

main_window.mainloop()
```

As the comments say you could use StringVar, linked to the label.  Then on_after would need to change StringVar instead of configuring the label.

Edit: For completeness a version with StringVar

```
main_window = tk.Tk()
var=tk.StringVar()
var.set("Hello World")
label_text = tk.Label(main_window, textvariable=var)

def on_after():
    var.set("Hello ") # set the StringVar instead of configuring the label.

label_text.grid(column=1, row=1)
label_text.after(3000, on_after)
main_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the StringVar() datatype

```
mytext = StringVar()
label_text = Label(main_window, text=mytext)
mytext.set("hello")
#after sometime change the text as required
mytext.set("new text")
```

hopefully, this will work.

Comment: That outputs "PYVAR0". I'm not sure why.

Comment: The use of `StringVar` is unrelated to this problem. The label can be updated without the use of `StringVar`. You _can_ use it, but that doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: If you use `StringVar` you have to use `textvariable=` instead of `text=`